# How to fix "aes128_enc_single' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: arduino

I am connecting a sensor to android device through arduino. I need to encrypt my sensor data and then send it to android device. But when I include aes128_enc_single(key, temp), It gives an error and said "aes128_enc_single' was not declared in this scope "
What should I do for this?

I have included AESLib.h library

My sample code is

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <AESLib.h>

uint8_t key[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31};

SoftwareSerial blue(2,3);

int i = 0;
float temp = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    blue.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

    i = analogRead(A0);
    temp = (i/1024.0)*500;

    Serial.println(temp);

    aes128_enc_single(key, temp);

    Serial.print("encrypted:");
    Serial.println(temp);

    blue.print("Encrypted Temperature: ");
    blue.println(temp);

    delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: You said that you included the library `AESLib.h` but can't see in the code. If it's properly included and existing in library folder of Arduino then there should be no error. Also you don't need to pass the result from  `aes128_enc_single()`

Comment: I have edited my code and provided the code in my post. Still the same error appears again.

Comment: Did you check if it is existing in the library folder? Or in the library menu of the arduino?

Comment: If the include file `AESLib.h` weren't existing (or found), you'd get a different error. Did you check which file was found and what it contains actually?

Comment: Thank you both ! I have checked AESLib.h and found that there is no function named aes128_enc_single(). So I have added the function and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

For people who run into this issue in the future:  Download the AESLib directly from GitHub instead of using the Arduino Library Manager.

//https://github.com/DavyLandman/AESLib

Comment: Why would this help?